# Enter Letter and change from upper case to lower case and vice versa?

Tags: java, string

So I have to write a program that does the following:

1. Enters 1 letter at a time and press enter ("A")
2. Pressing enter changes letter to upper or lower case ("a")
3. It outputs the result of pressing enter (The result is a)
4. Continue the above until the user enters a "." which ends the program

I'm not sure why my program will not work. It keeps saying "cannot resolve symbol" on the `letter.isUpperCase` and `letter.isLowerCase`. If you guys/gals can figure this out and if you see any more problems let me know! Thanks in advance!

```
import java.io.*;
class Letter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
        BufferedReader mVHS = new BufferedReader (inStream);

        String inData; //Store the input data in a String    
        int length;//Assign the length to the int data type
        String letter, result, result2; //Store the sentence in the String type

        //Enter a letter
        System.out.println("Type a letter one at a time");
        System.out.println("Press enter when a letter is entered");
        System.out.println("When done typing all the letters, press . to end the program");
        System.out.println("Enter a letter:");
        String userInput = mVHS.readLine();
        letter = userInput;

        result = letter.toUpperCase();
        result2 = letter.toLowerCase();

        if (letter.isUpperCase(letter.charAt(0)))
            System.out.println(result);
        else if (letter.isLowerCase(letter.charAt(0)))
            System.out.println(result2); 

        //while loop if sentence does not end with a "."
        while(letter.length() == 1){
        {
            if (letter.endsWith("."))
                System.out.println("Thank you come again."); //What the monitor outputs in this condition
            else  
                System.out.println("Enter another letter:");//What the monitor outputs in this condition
            userInput = mVHS.readLine();
            letter = userInput;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `String` does not have a `isLowerCase(char)` method. `Character` does.

Comment: are you sure you are making these program and looking for solutions at stackoverflow ? Are you for real?

Comment: Use some IDE like eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method named `isUpperCase` or `isLowerCase` on `String`. So, change from

```
 letter.isUpperCase(letter.charAt(0))
```

to

```
Character.isUpperCase(letter.charAt(0));
```

Comment: When I use this it keeps using my initial letter

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code

```
import java.io.*;
```

class Letter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader mVHS = new BufferedReader (inStream);


    String letter; //Store the sentence in the String type

    //Enter a letter
    System.out.println("Type a letter one at a time");
    System.out.println("Press enter when a letter is entered");
    System.out.println("When done typing all the letters, press . to end the program");
    System.out.println("Enter a letter:");
    String userInput = mVHS.readLine();
    letter = toggleCase(userInput);
       System.out.println(letter);

    //while loop if sentence does not end with a "."
    while(letter.length() == 1){
    {
        if (letter.endsWith("."))
            System.out.println("Thank you come again."); //What the monitor outputs in this condition
        else  
            System.out.println("Enter another letter:");//What the monitor outputs in this condition
        userInput = mVHS.readLine();

        letter = toggleCase(userInput);
        System.out.println(letter);
    }
    }
}

private static String toggleCase(String userInput) {
    String letter;
    String upperString;
    letter = userInput;

    upperString = letter.toUpperCase();


    if (letter.equals(upperString)){
        return (letter.toLowerCase());
    }
    else{
        return (upperString);
    }

}
```

}